# Найти количество символов в слове

Tags: c++

Есть массив на 80. В каждом элементе массива находится слово. Нужно подсчитать количество символов элементе массива.

Comment: Нужно просто найти длину слова, или количество каких-то определенных символов? И массив на 80 чего?

Comment: Мне просто нужно подсчитать количество символов с строке которая хранится в одном из элементов массива. 
Например: "hello" - 5 символов

Comment: `strlen` возвращает длину строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <string>

...

string massiv[80];

int element_id = 0; // номер элемента в массиве

cout << massiv[element_id].size();
```

Comment: Именно это мне мне было и нужно. Спасибо